# Should I receive a notification for my “upvoted" comments?

Tags: feature-request

If my comment “adds something useful to [a] post”, I’d simply like to know so - I’d like to be notified. I think that such a feature would, in the long run, improve the quality of comments. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Votes on comments are more similar to favs on Twitter/likes on FB in a way. The only functionality behind comment votes actually is that in case there are a lot of comments on a post, the ones with higher upvotes get displayed by default, not the chronologically oldest.

Question is slightly different than [What happens with deleted comments](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2429), but the answers given there apply to comment "votes" as well. Comments aren't guarateed to persist, so voting on them doesn't impact your reputations etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Thoughts: 1) Though the Facebook & Twitter comparison is accurate, the exact difference is that I would receive a notification if someone “liked” or “faved” my comment.  2) The feature would have nothing to do with reputation, or any explicit incentive - I simply think it’d be a beneficial that one be notified for a positive contribution to the community, whatever the circumstances. 3) I appreciate the linked to Q&A - it’s dispelled some of my previous held notions about the persistence of comments, despite the fact my belief in the feature req. holds. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

tbh, I'd like a downvote option on comments too; for the truly idiotic, yet not actually offensive ones - to quickly push them out of contention.

Theoretical wild example:-
OP wants to expand a drive partition.
First comment is 'Wipe your drive, reinstall your OS'

It's not offensive; it's not 'strictly wrong', you *could* do it that way if you were so inclined; but it would be a whole lot more work than a smarter answer.

As an answer it would quickly get down voted, & commented on itself, hopefully before the OP had chance to take up the idea.

As a comment, there's no 'defence mechanism' for it.

Comment: If anything would get me to install user scripts in my web browser, it would be to collapse all comments. Oh, and I need to see them to moderate. Two things.

Comment: If in doubt, flag. This is valid for comments as well.

Comment: ah, yes - I always forget comment flags are also categorised